# Visual Studio - Microsoft.bcl.build.targets, unload project option not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I'm getting the following error:

`This project references NuGet packages(s) that are missing on this computer. Use Nuget Package Restore to download them... This missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets`

When I run "Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Build -Version 1.0.21" in my Package Manager Console nothing happens.

I've tried to unload the project but, when I right click on the project name I don't see an option for "Unload".

This is the only error I'm seeing when I build the project.

Comment: where do you have the packages folder, at the same level of your project?

Comment: With the death of raw .NET Framework 4.0 support, nobody should use it any more. Why do you still need it? Remove everything related to it from your project files and packages.config.

Comment: @LexLi - That's what I was trying to figure out. I can delete it from packages.config fine but, I can't seem to delete from my project files.

Comment: @Zinov - I think so

Comment: Just remove in the package.config the dependency at that library, then go and try to install it again, be sure that you are pointing to the correct nuget source. If you have a local repository that doesn't have the package I would recommend you to point to the nuget online repository